# PHPUnit exits with error code 255 only when run with Xdebug enabled

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, xdebug

I am trying to generate coverage report for my php app which is built with on `symfony 2.8`

All the test cases run fine when I have disabled Xdebug.
However when I enable Xdebug, phpunit exits silently.

PHP app built on symfony 2.8
Xdebug 2.4.1
PHPUnit 5.7.6

When I check the exit code with `$?` it is 255.

So tried enabling php error logs in `php.ini`

`error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
display_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log`

I have also ensured that `/var/log/php-errors.log` has all required permissions.

I have two problems here

- PHPUnit exits silently only when Xdebug is enabled (works fine otherwise)
- No errors are found in the log to debug the above issue

Comment: I may suggest trying another xdebug version (in case if there is something wrong with this one). Also try different PHP version (be it newer one (7.x) or the same as your current but fresh install). If it's all the same there -- try debugging the PHPUnit to see where it will break.

Comment: You should check for xdebug's remote log. Can you isolate the test where it's happening, e.g. you could use `--testdox` to get a better look at which tests are executed and when it fails? Then test if you see the same behaviour when only running this test and try to isolate how/why xdebug chrashes. I expect there is some nasty segfault happening somewhere

Comment: Do you have `xdebug.halt_level` setted to any value? If yes there may be suppressed errors like `@do_something()` which does not produce any errors/logs but force php to stop executing

Comment: Looks like you do not have startup errors displayed yet `display_startup_errors = 1`, check in your php.ini. Also check you're editing the correct php.ini, this is also another common mistake. -Also for reference [PHP exit status 255: what does it mean?](https://serverfault.com/q/153634/69499)

Comment: Please also share how you enable and disable xdebug.